# how to disable symfony 2.5 emails for errors

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

i searched in the docs,
i find how to setup the config.yml to send emails with errors,
i find how to disable all delivery,
but not how to disable emails only about errors (and forexample, let FOSuserBundle send emails about password reset and so).

any idea?

Comment: Can you show your config file? Have looked at this http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html

Comment: yes i did, there is no log level corresponding to "do not send error mails at all", just some levels of error. (critical for 500, alert for 550...)